# Printing output of a Github Actions plugin in an issue created using another plugin

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, workflow, cicd

Currently, I have a Github Actions file checks for broken links in a repo's .md files and creates a new issue if it finds any broken links. It looks like this-

```
jobs:
  check-for-broken-links:
    name: Check for broken links
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      output: ${{ steps.checking_links.outputs }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - id: checking_links
        uses: gaurav-nelson/github-action-markdown-link-check@v1

  notify:
    name: Notify broken link(s)
    needs: check-for-broken-links
    if: failure()
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "BROKEN_LINKS=${{ needs.check-for-broken-links.outputs.output }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - uses: JasonEtco/create-an-issue@v2.9.1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        with:
          filename: '.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md'
```

And another file ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md which has the following in its body:

```
Please check the link(s):

{{ env.BROKEN_LINKS }}
```

Everything else is working as expected, but I can't get the new issue created to print the broken links. I have tried most of what I found online, but nothing seems to work. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks!